# interrupt() not working as expected (how does interrupt work?)

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, interrupt-handling

I want to interrupt a thread, but invoking `interrupt()` doesn't seem to work. Below is the sample code:

```
public class BasicThreadrRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Basic(), "thread1");
        t1.start();
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Basic(), "thread3");
        Thread t4 = new Thread(new Basic(), "thread4");
        t3.start();
        t1.interrupt();
        t4.start();
    }
}
class Basic implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        while(true) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.err.println("thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the output looks like thread 1 is still running. Can anyone explain this as well as how `interrupt()` works? Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The thread is still running simply because you catch `InterruptedException` and keep running. `interrupt()` primarily sets a flag in the `Thread` object, which you can check with `isInterrupted()`. It also causes some methods -- `sleep()`, `join` `Object.wait()`, in particular -- to return immediately by throwing an `InterruptedException`. It also causes some I/O operations to immediately terminate. If you're seeing the printouts from your `catch` block, then you can see that `interrupt()` is working.

Answer (score 17):

As others have said, you catch the interrupt, but do nothing with it. What you need to do is *propagate* the interrupt using logic such as,

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
    try{
        // do stuff
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // propagate interrupt
    }
}
```

Using looping logic, such as `while(true)` is just lazy coding. Instead, poll the thread's interrupted flag in order to determine termination via interruption.

Comment: Or you could move the try/catch outside the loop. ;)

Comment: Yes, but that was already mentioned by @MByD and it keeps that bad looping logic intact. :D

Comment: +1 for mentioning an alternative approach to <code>while ( true ) </code>
p.s. Thank you!

Comment: @mre InterruptedException is a checked exception, if //do stuff is doing with Thread.sleep it will work...what about otherwise? Do I need to have Thread.sleep mandatory?

Answer (score 0):

++1, in addition to other answers. I believe the misconception about this was that it seemed the `try/catch` block finished its job after the `Thread.sleep(1000);` call i.e. *try to sleep for 1000ms, catch anything that might interrupt my sleep attempt*.

What is happening actually is that the `try/catch` block is still very much active while sleeping i.e. *try to sleep for 1000ms, catch anything that might interrupt during my sleep*

Hence the reason why the exception is being caught immediately (and afterwards) since the thread barely just started its sleep.